# Is there a way to have BACNet MS/TP devices in a BACNet/IP situation?

Tags: networking, ip-address, bacnet

I have a raspberry pi using BACpypes for python, acting as a VLAN router to a bunch of radio slave devices. (I am actually using something very similar to https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes/blob/master/samples/IP2VLANRouter.py) I am attempting to get this system integrated into the building here. I am told they are unable to be integrated since the slave devices show up as MS/TP devices and would have to have their own IP. Is there a way for me to get them to show up with an address?

In YABE they show up as `Device 8012 - 12 via 192.168.1.103:47808` but a regular IP device shows up as `Device 599 - 192.168.1.103:47808`. I am told that the slave devices would need a MAC address with a BACNet UDP appended, for example `192.168.1.103.xxx.xxx`. I am not sure what these x'd numbers would be nor how to implement.

Comment: A BACnet IP to MSTP router will be needed to translate between the two physical layers (Ethernet, and RS485)

Answer (score 0):

If you send me a 'Object-Names' YabeMap (export) file, I could take a very quick glance; but it sounds like you have a BACnet 'Router' - 'Device 599 - 192.168.1.103:47808', that is acting as an IP (/ BACnet/IP) communication-point/access to the MS/TP (/ BACnet MS/TP) device - 'Device 8012 - 12 via 192.168.1.103:47808'.

I believe '12' is it's DNET (Destination Network) value, and yes, you will also need it's DADR (Destination Address)/MAC address value, in order to communicate with it - to allow for the 'transport' of service requests onto it via the router device.

(The 'Object-Names' YabeMap (export) file will have it's MAC (/'Routed') address buried within it; I can't remember if you can exposed the MAC address via YABE in another more visual way, but there's always the VTS (Visual Test Shell) advanced/power tool.)

(I thought I recall YABE displaying the MAC address incorrectly as a trailing/"via"? IP address format.)